# Managing Visual State

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have a universal Windows 8.1 app that uses the same code in the code-behind files but has significantly different layouts for PC/tablet and phone. To make the transition to Windows 10 easier (and so I only have to manage one code-behind file) I want my project to use only one XAML file. I don't know much about view states but I'd guess that's how I'd keep separate layouts for the different platforms. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You don't have to make that change to be ready for windows 10. This [link](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/04/02/Creating-different-page-views-for-Windows-Apps-based-on-the-device.aspx) shows how you can keep separate views for diferrent device families that share the same code behind.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can I also do this in Windows 8.1? I'm still adding features to my app and it would be great if I only had to manage one code-behind.

Comment: No I don't think you can do that in windows 8.1. It would have been great though. For Windows 8.1 you'll have to go with visual states. [Useful link to do it in blend](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/11/windows-81-how-to-use-visual-states-in.html) . Maybe create an empty parent visual state and two child visual states for pc and phone

Comment: Thanks again. Jerry Nixon's videos are great (almost as good as Rob Tabor's in my opinion). There is one thing that I can't figure out how to change with a visual state, and that is the ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions for my grid. I'm assuming that since they (the Row and ColumnDefinitionCollections) are collections, and not value properties, I am not able to modify them with a visual state. I could change them in code as necessary, and change the values back and forth while I'm designing them, but is there a better way?

Comment: If you create an empty(or containing all the common stuff) "parent" visual state and two visual states for mobile and desktop then in one of them you can have a grid with x columns and on the other a grid with y collumns.

Comment: I have objects in this grid though, and I can't change the parent-child structure of a scene in a Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the [Window.Changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.sizechanged.aspx) in your code behind and call [VisualStateManager.GoToState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate.aspx) to tell your UI to apply a VisualState you've defined.

In Windows 10 there will be [AdaptiveTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx)s that will eliminate the need to manually listen to the Window.SizeChanged event, so it's the closest and easiest analogy.